# Jquery: Open link in new window. Re-usable with custom dimensions per link

Tags: jquery, window, custom-data-attribute

In certain situations I like to open links in new windows with jquery. I was wondering how I could keep common code for all links, while modifying the width and height per link?

(The width/height is the width/height of the window that opens when the link is clicked).

I was thinking of using a custom data attribute (like: data-window-width and data-window-height).

I have made a start but am not sure of how to handle the width and height variables.

HTML:

```
   <a href="SOME_LINK_HERE" class="linkSocial" 
data-window-width="700" data-window-height="400">link text</a>
```

JAVASCRIPT:

```
//Open social links in new window
$('body').on('click', 'a.linkSocial', function() {
    var width = 'width' + $(this).data('window-width');
    var height = 'height' + $(this).data('window-height');
    //Not sure what to do next with width and height!
    newwindow=window.open($(this).attr('href'),'','height=400,width=770');
    if (window.focus) {newwindow.focus()}
    return false;
});
```

Comment: Not enough information is given. What is the relationship between the link and the width/height? Also, it should be, `$(this).data('window-width/height');`.

Comment: The width/height relates to the window that is opened when clicking the link. Will change the post to reflect this and your correction.

Comment: Am I missing some obvious correlation between the two? I mean, the way you're doign this is fine, you just need to do `'height="'+height+'px"'`, and `'width="'+width+'px"'`